# Относительные положение и размер элементов интерфейса в PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qlabel, resizeevent

Я хочу, чтобы при изменении размера главного окна все `QPushButton`, `QLineEdit`, `QLabel` тоже меняли своё положение, а если возможно, то и размер, чтобы сохранить пропорции интерфейса.

На данный момент в *PyQt5* я могу только в пикселях указывать положение элементов. Надеюсь, что понятно объяснил.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, свой код. И интерфейс тоже было бы неплохо.

Answer (score 1):

Предоставлять минимальный пример - в ваших же интересах, да и наше время сэкономите.

Метод `resizeEvent` вызывается каждый раз, когда изменяется размер окна, 
поэтому это правильное место для перемещений и изменений.

То что вы спрашиваете, может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.w = 400
        self.h = 400
        self.resize(self.w, self.h)
        self.setMinimumSize(self.w/2, self.h/2)

        self.widthFactor  = 1
        self.heightFactor = 1

        self.labelPix = QtWidgets.QLabel(self, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)        
        self.labelPix.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("im.png").scaled(self.w * self.widthFactor, 
                                                               self.h * self.heightFactor))  
        self.labelPix.move(0, 0)
        self.labelPix.adjustSize()

        self.label    = QtWidgets.QLabel("Label", self, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)        
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: {}pt Arial; background:lightblue".format(20*self.heightFactor))
        self.label.resize(self.w*self.widthFactor, self.h*0.25*self.heightFactor)  
        self.label.adjustSize()

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(" Hello World ! ", self)
        self.lineEdit.resize(self.w*0.75*self.widthFactor, self.h*0.1*self.heightFactor) 

        self.button   = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.clickButton)
        self.button.resize(self.w*0.25*self.widthFactor, self.h*0.2*self.heightFactor) 

    def clickButton(self):
        self.label.setText(self.lineEdit.text())
        self.label.adjustSize()
        self.label.move(self.rect().center() - self.label.rect().center() - QPoint(0, self.h*0.25*self.heightFactor))

    def setLabelPix(self):
        self.labelPix.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("im.png").scaled(self.w * self.widthFactor, 
                                                               self.h * self.heightFactor))  
        self.labelPix.move(0, 0)
        self.labelPix.adjustSize()
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: {}pt Arial; background:lightblue".format(20*self.heightFactor))
        self.label.adjustSize()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.widthFactor  = self.rect().width() / 400
        self.heightFactor = self.rect().height()/ 400        

        self.labelPix.move(self.rect().center() - self.labelPix.rect().center() ) # - QPoint(0, 150)) 
        self.label.move(self.rect().center() - self.label.rect().center() - QPoint(0, self.h/4*self.heightFactor))
        self.lineEdit.resize(self.w*0.75*self.widthFactor, self.h*0.1*self.heightFactor)
        self.lineEdit.move(self.rect().center() - self.lineEdit.rect().center()) 
        self.button.resize(self.w*0.25*self.widthFactor, self.h*0.2*self.heightFactor)
        self.button.move(self.rect().center() - self.button.rect().center() - QPoint(0, -self.h*0.3*self.heightFactor))
        self.setLabelPix() 
        super(Window, self).resizeEvent(event)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setWindowTitle('При изменении размера главного окна меняем все положение и размеры.')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]